# How to properly share a VS project with references to another computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a project here that compiles fine, but it uses a reference to a DLL that is not from NuGet.  I added it using References-Add Reference-Browse.

Unfortunately, the reference appears (from clicking on properties of the reference in Solution explorer) that the DLL location is [project dir\bin\debug] and [project dir\bin\release].  These don't seem appropriate directories to add to source control to share to another computer.  It also doesn't seem right that I would add both directories.

So the end result when I transfer to another computer, is of course "are you missing a reference?".

What I want to do: Put the reference in a directory under my solution, add it to source control, and add the reference to Visual Studio using that path.

I can't see how to accomplish this, or anything like it, except to add the DLL in every build configuration directory to source control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Direct reference

I think what you're doing is almost correct. You just have to make sure that when you add the reference you point to the right file.

1. Put the library into a folder, e.g. `ThirdPartyLibs`.
2. Add the file to git (e.g. with `git add`).
3. Add the reference to project with Add Reference... and point to the file file in the newly created folder. You may want to set it up as `Copy Local`.

## Nuget way

One option is to have a local nuget source:

1. Package a library as nuget package and put in a local folder inside your git repo, e.g. MyLocalNuget
2. Add NuGet.config at the solution level. Example:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
   <solution>
       <add key="Local NuGet" value="MyLocalNuget"/>
   </solution>
   <packageSources>
       <clear /> 
       <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
   </packageSources>
   </configuration>
   ```
3. Add the library to the projects using normal NuGet way.

Comment: First way works!  Thank you.  Not that it matters at this point: I have no idea what the command is to do Nuget step 1.